# JQuery Cycle Plugin Issue

Tags: jquery

This is the first time I've ever tried JQuery basically because I couldnt get the AJAX Slideshow to work.

This is not working out for me.  Its basically showing the images stacked on one another.

Im running this with ASP.NET 2.0. with Visual Studio 2010.

Does anyone have a clue about what Im doing wrong here?

Here is my code, which I think is pretty identical to the example that came with the download:

```
1.<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="DaVincisApp1.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css"> 
.slideshow { height: 232px; width: 232px; margin: auto }
.slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.min.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="slideshow">
   <img alt="Image1" src="Images/Slide1.jpg" />
   <img alt="Image2" src="Images/Slide2.jpg" />
   <img alt="Image3" src="Images/Slide3.jpg" />
   <img alt="Image4" src="Images/Slide4.jpg" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure that jquery and the cycle plugin are loaded properly (you could check with the firebug network tab for example)

Comment: Im not sure at all because this is the first time that Ive used JQuery. All I did was add three js files--- jquery-1.4.1.js and jquery-1.4.1.min.js and jquery.cycle.min.js to the Scripts Directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of of the .js files is important as well as the script tag itself.

This works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.min.js"></script>
```

This doesnt work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote mark in `$(.slideshow').cycle(`. Maybe that's it?

Answer (score 0):

Check that scripts are loaded. Are images displayed ?

Comment: The images display just stacked on top of one another.  How do I check to see if the scripts are loaded??  Like I mentioned to this other guy:  All I did was add three js files--- jquery-1.4.1.js and jquery-1.4.1.min.js and jquery.cycle.min.js to the Scripts Directory

Comment: what does that mean: loaded?:

Comment: @Paul what browser are you using?

Comment: I figured it out the problem was with the script tag itself.